# Why does Inkscape on Mac require XQuartz?

Tags: macos, inkscape, xquartz

As far as I know it uses GTK3 which does not require XQuartz. So why are they *still* using such an awkward and ancient system?

Comment: This is an area of active development — see https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/issues/84  There are builds which you can get without XQuartz already, but they aren't yet considered stable/production.  (But see the link, since this comment will go out of date.)

Answer (score 1):

I wondered the same thing. There must be some historical reason. Likely, it's a matter of prioritization for the core dev team. The Inkscape team has been aware of the issue and you can find more information on their [GitLab Issue](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/issues/84) overviewing the concerns/considerations.

Update: The [Inkscape v1 beta](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/?latest=1) for mac is now native and no longer require XQuartz. See [release notes](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Mac_Application).